# Android fetching events from calendar using range of dates

Tags: android, events, android-calendar

Actually, I need to fetch calendar events for week, month, selected date and today. I am succeded for week and month but not in selected day.

```
String mainDate[] = dayValue.split("-");
            int year, month, day;

            year = Integer.parseInt(mainDate[0]);
            month = Integer.parseInt(mainDate[1]);
            day = Integer.parseInt(mainDate[2]);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(year, month - 1, day, 0, 0, 0);
long after = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

            SimpleDateFormat formatterr = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");

            Calendar endOfDay = Calendar.getInstance();
Cursor cursor;

            endOfDay.set(year, month - 1, day, 22, 59, 59);

            Uri.Builder builder = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/instances/when").buildUpon();
            long now = new Date().getTime();
            ContentUris.appendId(builder, after);
            ContentUris.appendId(builder, endOfDay.getTimeInMillis());

            String[] projection = new String[] { "event_id", "title", "description", "dtstart", "dtend", "eventLocation", "accessLevel", "allDay", Instances.BEGIN, Instances.END };

            String sortOrder = "startDay ASC, startMinute ASC";

            cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(builder.build(), projection, null, null, sortOrder);
```

//Ahead, same code, for loop and getting data.

Now, the problem is, i.e. if I am getting 14th may events only, then I have got 13th may event with it, and that event is from facebook and its all day event. So I dont need that event, I need only 14th may event.

Please advice me.

Answer (score 0):

There is an inbuilt query() method in CalendarContract.Instances. Hope it works in your scenario.

```
Date startDate= Create an object of date with the your startdate range; // in ur case may be 14thMay
Date endDate = Create an object of date with the your enddate range; // in ur case may be 14thMay
long beginMillis = startDate.getTime() ;//the number of milliseconds since Jan. 1, 1970, midnight GMT.  
    long endMillis = endDate.getTime() ;
Cursor cursor = CalendarContract.Instances.query(contentResolver, projection, beginMillis, endMillis);
```